# Regex for fix length string which allow space(s) at end only. C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm need regex which

1. a-z, A-Z, 0-9 allowed.
2. Fixed with 20 characters.
3. Space(s) at the beginning or middle **not allowed**.
4. Space(s) at the end **allowed**.

Example:

```
12345678901234567890 [Match]

1234567890           [Match]

abcde12345           [Match]

 abcdefg             [Not match]

ab cdefg             [Not match]
```

I use this regex, it works fine, but it's really long and hard to maintain.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{19}\s{1}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}\s{2}
|[a-zA-Z0-9]{17}\s{3}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}\s{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}\s{5}
|[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}\s{6}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{13}\s{7}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s{8}
|[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}\s{9}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}\s{10}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}\s{11}
|[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s{12}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}\s{13}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\s{14}
|[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\s{15}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s{16}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s{17}
|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s{18}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s{19}|\s{20}
```

Please help, thank you.

---

**UPDATE**.

In fact i need to check very long string.

At first, before i asking this question, my regex is look like this (1st regex)

```
^[\s\d]{25}\d{6}[0-1]{1}\d{24}[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\\_\=\+\/\,\?\<\>\;\:\"\'\w\s\.]{30}(\s{3}|\d{3})(\s{4}|\d{4})[\s|00|10|20|40]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{20}[\s\w\d]{0,32}$
```

After i ask the question, my regex is look like this (2nd regex)

```
^[\s\d]{25}\d{6}[0-1]{1}\d{24}[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\\_\=\+\/\,\?\<\>\;\:\"\'\w\s\.]{30}(\s{3}|\d{3})(\s{4}|\d{4})[\s|00|10|20|40]{2}(?=.{20})[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*[\s]{0,32}$
```

Suppose i split this regex in 3 parts.

```
Part1:[\s\d]{25}\d{6}[0-1]{1}\d{24}[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\\_\=\+\/\,\?\<\>\;\:\"\'\w\s\.]{30}(\s{3}|\d{3})(\s{4}|\d{4})[\s|00|10|20|40]{2}

Part2:[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{20} changed to (?=.{20})[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*

Part3:[\s\w\d]{0,32}
```

Part1 is work fine.

Part2 requirement was changed, so i was changed it to **"(?=.{20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*"**

Part3 is the problem when i change part2.

**Example**

```
00202510027680           1901160000000000000000000007000Test Test 009                 069      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The string end with 32 spaces. 
If i add 1 more space 1st regex not match. But the 2nd regex match. The correct is not match.

How can i modify part2 (or part3) to meet the requirement. Thank you.

[demo for 1st regex](https://regex101.com/r/dO1pL2/2)

[demo for 2nd regex](https://regex101.com/r/mI9sX3/1)

Comment: You are using the regex in .NET, and testing it on a Web site that does not support .NET regex syntax. Here is a working .NET regex for you: [`@"^[\s\d]{25}\d{6}[01]\d{24}[-!@#$%^&*()\\_=+/,?<>;:""'\w\s.]{30}(\s{3}|\d{3})(\s{4}|\d{4})(\s|00|10|20|40){2}[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{20}(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}\s*)[\s\w\d]{0,32}$"`](http://goo.gl/TQV2S4). Please test and let me know if it works for you. Note that `[\s|00|10|20|40]{2}` matches 2 characters: either a whitespace, or `0`, `1`, `2`, or `4`. If you need to match 2 whitespaces, or two `00`s, or two `10`s, etc. you need to use `(...)` (see my pattern).

Comment: I think it nearly works, but at 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' cannot have any space at the begining or middle, allow at the end only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please help, thank you

Comment: I need an access to my desktop to check. The technique is to use a lookbehind to impose an additional check. I'm afraid the oattern is becoming too unmaintainable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=.{20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO1pL2/1)

In this expression, the length of 20 chars is enforced with the positive lookahead `(?=.{20}$)`. Since matching pattern only matches A-Z, a-z and 0-9, the `.` in the lookahead is possible.

*Regex explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{20}$)` - The string must be 20 characters long
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - zero or more letters or digits (a `+` can be used instead of `*`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string

C#:

```
var reg = @"^(?=.{20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*$";
```

Comment: Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew, i think its work perfectly. But in fact i need to check very long string. I've use your answer as part of my fully regex. My regex look like this 

[\s\d]{25}\d{6}[0-1]{1}\d{24}[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\\_\=\+\/\,\?\<\>\;\:\"\'\w\s\.]{30}(\s{3}|\d{3})(\s{4}|\d{4})[\s|00|10|20|40]{2}(?=.{20})[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*

.

And i need to append some thing like [\s\w\.]{32} to my fully regex. How could i do that?

Comment: Please provide an example string. Your regex is incorrect at first glance, because you are using a character class instead of grouping (here: `[00|10|20|40]{2}`).

Comment: 1st string "00202510027680           1901160000000000000000000007000Test Test 009                 069      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[32 spaces or any characters]" --> [Matched], 2rd string "00202510027680           1901160000000000000000000007000Test Test 009                 069      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[no space or character]" --> same as 1st string but have no spaces or characters  [Matched]

Comment: When dealing with length restrictions, you must use boundaries (`\b`, lookarounds)/anchors (`^`/`$`), BTW.

Comment: I'd rather you add that to the question and specify the requirements. [It does not work with the provided string](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cs%5cd%5d%7b25%7d%5cd%7b6%7d%5b01%5d%5cd%7b24%7d%5b!%40%23%24%25%5e%26*()_%3d%2b%2f%2c%3f%3c%3e%3b%3a%22%27%5cw%5cs%e2%80%8c.-%5d%7b30%7d(%3f%3a%5cs%7b3%7d%7c%5cd%7b3%7d)(%3f%3a%5cs%7b4%7d%7c%5cd%7b4%7d)(%3f%3a%5cs%7c00%7c10%7c20%7c40)%7b2%7d(%3f%3d%5b%5cw%5cs%5d%7b20%7d%24)%5cw*%5cs*%24&i=00202510027680+1901160000000000000000000007000Test+Test+009+069+aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa). BTW, you left out `$` from the lookahead. Why?

Comment: I really appreciate for your response. I going to add my requirement and example to the question, wait a moment please. BTW, i'am newbie to regex. I use trial and error to test my regex, so i think its have something stupid with my regex.

Comment: i just add requirement and example to the question. Please help.

Comment: Gosh I hate regex. People should get paid extra money for Regex knowledge.